# No error message shows up even if no Radiobutton is selected - what's wrong with my code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, radio-button

So I have two functions:

```
def Driver_Form():
    canvas.delete("all")
    root.configure(bg="cornflower blue")
    canvas.config(width=root.winfo_screenwidth(), height=root.winfo_screenheight(),
                  bg="sky blue") 
...

myvar1 = StringVar() #IntVar()
Male = Radiobutton(canvas, text = "Male", variable = myvar1, value = 1)
canvas.create_window(734, 265, window = Male, height = 25, width = 70)

Female = Radiobutton(canvas, text="Female", variable=myvar1, value = 2)
canvas.create_window(825, 265, window=Female, height=25, width=90)

Other = Radiobutton(canvas, text="Rather not say", variable=myvar1, value = 3)
canvas.create_window(940, 265, window=Other, height=25, width=120)

Next_button = Button(root, text="Next", anchor=CENTER, command=lambda: check_Driver(FName_Entry, LName_Entry,
                                                                                        day_combobox, month_combobox,
                                                                                        year_combobox, myvar1, Email_Entry, Phone_Entry))
    Next_button.configure(width=10, bg="black", fg="blue", border=10)
    canvas.create_window(920, 450, anchor=NW, window=Next_button)
```

the `Next_button` leads to another function:

```
def check_Driver(FName_Entry, LName_Entry, day_combobox, month_combobox, year_combobox,  myvar1, Email_Entry,
                 Phone_Entry, event=None):
...

if myvar1 != 1 or 2 or 3:
    error_blank2 = Message(root, text="Please don't leave any field/s blank", anchor=CENTER, bg="red", width=1000)
    canvas.create_window(600, 450, anchor=NW, window=error_blank2)
```

I am trying to make sure that an error message shows up if none of the radio buttons are clicked out of male, female and other. However, I dont know what is wrong but it doesn't seem to work and no error message shows up even if none of the Radiobuttons are clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least two big problems. First, `myvar1` will never be 1, 2, or 3 because `myvar1` isn't an integer. It's an instance of `StringVar`. So, the first thing you need to change is that you need to use `int(myvar1.get())` in your `if` statements so that you're comparing the value stored in the variable rather than the instance of `StringVar` itself.

When you fix that, you'll have another problem. `if myvar1 != 1 or 2 or 3` is not doing what you think it does. It is logically the same as `if (myvar != 1) or (bool(2)) or (bool(3))`. Since `bool(2)` will always return `True`, the body of the `if` statement will always run.

If you want to check that `myvar1` isn't one of the values 1, 2, or 3, you can do it one of these ways:

```
if int(myvar1.get()) not in (1, 2, 3):
```

-or-

```
value = int(myvar1.get())
if value != 1 and value != 2 and value != 3:
```

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is wrong. The condition you wrote does not check whether the value is 1, 2, or 3, but it checks whether it is not 1 or whether 2 and 3 are numbers different from 0.

To check whether myvar is something else than 1, 2, or 3, use:

```
if myvar1.get() not in [1, 2, 3]:
```